# How to escape Trademark and Copyright characters in XML output from PHP

Tags: php, xml

My PHP app is outputting an XML file and some of the output can potentially contain Trademark and/or Copyright characters.  Is there a way to escape these characters in the output?

Thanks!

Comment: Please describe the steps you've taken so far to implement the desired functionality.

Comment: Why do you want to escape them? They hold no special meaning in XML. You just need to be consistent in your use of character encodings.

Answer (score 7):

The only special characters you *need* to escape in XML are:

- `< - &lt;`
- `> - &gt;`
- `& - &amp;`
- `" - &quot;`
- `' - &apos; / &#39;`

You can use the escaped variant in attribute values or text nodes. The following 2 examples represent the same content.

```
<foo>&lt;Hello@World&gt;</foo>
<foo><![CDATA[<Hello@World>]]></foo>
```

The nodeValue of `<foo/>` is always `<Hello@World>`.

The first is a text node, the second a cdata section. In cdata sections the entities are not allowed and the sequence `]]>` is forbidden. DOM will automatically split a CDATA section if it contains `]]>`.

Other special characters like © only need to be escaped if you're not using a unicode capable encoding for your XML. If you want a simple ASCII XML, you can write the special characters as numeric character references. The number is the codepoint of the character in Unicode.

- `© - &#169; / &#xA9;`

Schemas and DTDs can define named character entity references. These are not available in XML, but can be available in a format that is based on XML. (X)HTML is an example.

- `© - &copy;`

If you use DOM, it will take care of it as needed.

In UTF-8, only XML special characters will be escaped.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$dom->appendChild($dom->createElement('foo'));
$dom->documentElement->appendChild($dom->createTextNode('<©€äöü>'));

echo $dom->saveXml();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<foo>&lt;©€äöü&gt;</foo>
```

In ASCII, a lot more will be escaped:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'ASCII');
$dom->appendChild($dom->createElement('foo'));
$dom->documentElement->appendChild($dom->createTextNode('<©€äöü>'));

echo $dom->saveXml();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ASCII"?>
<foo>&lt;&#169;&#8364;&#228;&#246;&#252;&gt;</foo>
```

Comment: Replacing the special characters with &#153; and &#174; did the trick!  Thanks everyone for the help!!!